# Hex into unsigned integer

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, hex

I'm trying to convert a string, split it and then take the hex and turn it into an unsigned integer
(for example, the string in the example would be `"read16 8033B21A"`).
I've been stuck on this one for a long time.

Any points would be very appreciated?

```
else if (strncmp(input, "read16 ", 7) == 0){
    char * tempaddr;
    sscanf(input, "read16 %c", &tempaddr); 
    unsigned int addr;
    sscanf(tempaddr, "%x", &addr);
    unsigned int memvalue=debugger_read_16(addr);
}
```

It likes to segfault after and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You are writing char to char pointer in first `sscanf`. No wonder it crashes

Comment: You are passing the wrong type to sscanf and it is an uninitialized pointer to boot.  So much error in so little code.  Simply use `sscanf(input, "read16 %x", &addr)`

Comment: Or, even simpler, use `sscanf(input + 7, "%x", &addr);` since you've already checked the first 7 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `%x` format specifier, which matches an unsigned hexadecimal number directly like

```
char str[]="read16 8033B21A";
unsigned n;
sscanf(str, "%*s %8x", &n);
printf("\n%u", n);
```

This gives:

```
2150871578
```

The `%*s` reads a string till a white space and then discards it. `*` is for assignment suppression. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for information about the `scanf()` family of functions.

Then the white space is read after which 8 characters are read as unsigned hexadecimal into the variable `n`.

You can use the `%u` format specifier to print the `unsigned int` variable.

---

And in your program,

```
char * tempaddr;
sscanf(input, "read16 %c", &tempaddr)
```

doesn't look right.

It should've been

```
char tempaddr;
sscanf(input, "read16 %c", &tempaddr)
```

because `sscanf()` expects an address to which the value will be written. If `tempaddr` were an uninitialized pointer, illegal memory access is what will probably happen because `tempaddr` could be having some garbage value which happens to be the address of a memory location the program is not supposed to access.

Answer (score 0):

In other words what comments saying are change this:

```
char * tempaddr;
sscanf(input, "read16 %c", &tempaddr);
```

to something like this

```
char tempaddr[32];
sscanf(input, "read16 %s", tempaddr);
```

Size 32 here is arbitrary make sure it's enough.
Hope that helps.

Comment: `%s` should not be used without specifying max width limit.

Comment: I know that, 32 here is AS I said is arbitrary, so what number you expect me to put there as `%??s`? 32?

Comment: If `tempaddr` is declared as `char[32]`, then `%32s` has the same problem as `%s`: possible buffer overflow. In this example largest possible limit can be `%31s`.